# Analysis of proportions across space and time

Tags: regression, logistic, proportion, biostatistics, ordered-logit

I'm currently working on a project and trying to determine the best way to analyze my data. I am looking at how temperature influences the reproductive development of a native fish species.

Our measurement of reproductive development is to come up with a proportion of the cells in the ovary at different developmental stages (1-5, with 1 being the least developed ovarian cell and 5 being an egg ready to be laid, and then 6 which are basically "empty cells" which just had been an egg that was laid). The higher the proportion of cells in 4-5 the more developed, and 6 means proof of recent reproduction. Fish were collected at various sites from upstream to downstream, with the assumption the downstream temperatures are higher and that reproductive development would occur earlier than upstream fish. We also collected these fish throughout the spawning period, so it would be expected to have little development at all sites in Feb and high development in late April/May.

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to analyze this? We want to know if there are differences in development between sites, taking into account the date collected (earlier=all fish not very developed, later =all fish very developed regardless of site). I was thinking maybe some sort of logistic or ordinal regression, but I'm not sure if that can account for all the variables at once?

Comment: Total sample size? How many sites? How many sampling times per site? ...

Comment: the total sample size is approximately 5-10 per site (though it isn't consistent). Close to maybe 400 total fish. We sampled this year 6 times per site at 9 sites.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.